# Why in solidity proxies from position's index subtract one

Tags: solidity

I'm learning Proxy pattern in Solidity, and have noticed, that in the ERC1967 contract offsets always decreases by one: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/proxy/ERC1967/ERC1967Upgrade.sol#L18-L19

What's the purpose of such deceasing?

Answer (score 1):

Assigning the value into storage slot ID calculated from a hash of a string (and not from a hash of a number, or even just slot ID <some low number>) decreases the risk of clash with another storage variable.

And subtracting 1 from the value decreases the probability even further, as there's no known input that would result in this value if it was hashed.

---

See the Rationale section of [ERC-1967](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1967)

> Furthermore, a `-1` offset is added so the preimage of the hash cannot be known, further reducing the chances of a possible attack.